# Return to original buffer after viewing errors in quickfix window in latex-suite

Tags: vim, latex, latex-suite

When I compile a latex file with latex-suite, shows me the errors in a quickfix window, and the main window shows me where the error ocurred. this is very useful. However, when done fixing the bug, I would like to return to the buffer and exact location I was in, close the quickfix and preview windows, and continue editing. Is there a way to do this, other than by hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can type <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> to go to where you were.

Comment: Ah nice, I didn't know Ctrl-o works across buffers. Doesn't close the preview and quickfix windows, but i suppose I could live with closing those by hand, if there is no built-in way of doing it.